# Python Dynamic Printing with different loops

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, printing, flush

I have a segment of a function below:

```
        if x > thickness:
            transmission.append(energy[0])
            count += 1
            alive = 0
            if LOUD:
                print("{} %".format(count/N))

        elif x < 0:
            absorption.append(energy[0])
            count += 1
            alive = 0
            if LOUD:
                print("{} %".format(count/N))
        else:
            # scatter or absorb
            if np.random.random(1) < cur_scat / Sig_t:
                # scatter, pick new mu and energy
                mu = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 1)
                energy = np.random.uniform(alpha * energy, energy, 1)

            else:
                # absorbed
                absorption.append(energy[0])
                count += 1
                alive = 0
                if LOUD:
                    print("{} %".format(count/N))
```

and I want the "prints" to each overwrite the latest print so that one value is expressed as a percentage in one line at any given time. I saw some other things online but they were flushing in the same loop. How can I do this with different loops?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your platform/environment.

You can't "unoutput" the old value, you need a way to overwrite it by adding *more* output.

Some platforms let you use a carriage-return (`'\r'`) to reset to the beginning of the line

Others may interpret backspace characters etc.

Generally it's best to use a library like curses (or [blessings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings)) to allow you to program a solution in less platform dependant way.

The examples on the link are using `print` statements, so are for Python 2.x. If you change them to `print(...)` they should work find in Python 3.x

> Coding with Blessings looks like this…
>
> ```
> from blessings import Terminal
>
> t = Terminal()
>
> print t.bold('Hi there!')
> print t.bold_red_on_bright_green('It hurts my eyes!')
>
> with t.location(0, t.height - 1):
>
> print 'This is at the bottom.'
> ```

Comment: Do you have a specific suggestion using one of those libraries?

Comment: @SterlingButters, Do you know how to use `pip`? I think if you install `blessings` you should be able to work from the examples eg using `location`

Comment: Sorry my response is so late, blessings does not work with my IDE (PyCharm)... I resolved with pyprind which does work in my IDE as a progress bar that was essentially what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Used pyprind progress bar for highest level for loop